# Finesse Class<E> into Class<E[]>

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class AbstractRESTClientService<E extends IDable<String>> 
    implements GenericService<E, String> {


    private Class<E> classType;
    private Class<E[]> classArray;
    private String controllerPath;

    public AbstractRESTClientService(final Class<E> classType, 
        final Class<E[]> classArray, 
        final String controllerPath) {
            this.classType = classType;
            this.classArray = classArray;
            this.controllerPath = controllerPath;
            this.webService = new GenericWebClientService<E>();
        }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate classType into classArray so that I don't need to pass in classArray as a parameter?

Comment: in theory you could do `Class<T[]> arrClazz = (Class<T[]> )) Array.newInstance(clazz, 0).getClass();` but i'm not sure is it best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to think this is the best way to do it, but here's how I've handled it.

```
public abstract class AbstractRESTClientService<E extends IDable<String>> 
    implements GenericService<E, String> {


private Class<E> classType;
private Class<E[]> classArray;
private String controllerPath;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractRESTClientService(final Class<E[]> classArray, 
    final String controllerPath) {
        this.classType = (Class<E>) classArray.getComponentType();
        this.classArray = classArray;
        this.controllerPath = controllerPath;
        this.webService = new GenericWebClientService<E>();
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```